# TWTweetComposeViewController memory leak with ARC enabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code, which is causing a leak, despite ARC being enabled on that file:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

[tweetViewController setInitialText:[self facebookAndTwitterStatus]];

tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
        // the user finished composing a tweet
    } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
        // the user cancelled composing a tweet
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

[self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

[self hideSettingsPopover];
```

Obviously i don't have a release, but how can i get rid of this leak?

Comment: I don't know why i've been downvoted. This is a genuine problem, that Apple's method results in a leak. And yet nobody else has asked about it before?

Comment: How do you know you have a leak?

Comment: If you're going to ask us to debug your code, without showing any effort or attempt at solving this yourself, the _very least_ you could do would be to tell us a) where the leak is, and b) how you discovered it.

Comment: code doesn't leak — objects do. So what object is supposed to be leaking?

Comment: Raise a bug with apple. They do listen. Just provide a sample project which exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use __block on your TwTweetViewController variable tweetViewController
and set tweetViewController to nil in your completion handler.

```
**__block** TweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

[tweetViewController setInitialText:[self facebookAndTwitterStatus]];

tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
        // the user finished composing a tweet
    } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
        // the user cancelled composing a tweet
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    **tweetViewController = nil;**
};
```

The __block copies your tweetViewController and it's released when you set it to nil.
This is explained in Transitioning to ARC release notes.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Not sure why your question was down voted.